# mommy Recipe with OneToOne

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, model-mommy

I am using `model_mommy` with Django to create test objects. I want to implement `Recipe` functionality. I have a model `Teacher` and a model `TeacherSchedule`:

```
Teacher(models.Model):
   some fields ...


TeacherSchedule(models.Model):
   teacher = models.OneToOneField(
        'Teacher',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='schedule',
    )
   some fields...
```

The Recipe I try to use then:

```
schedule = Recipe(
    TeacherSchedule,
)

teacher_with_schedule = Recipe(
    Teacher,
    schedule=foreign_key('schedule'),
)
```

However, when I run my tests, it seems that the `TeacherSchedule` object is not created. Am I doing something wrong with the `Recipe`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `''` from `'schedule'`:

```py
schedule = Recipe(
    TeacherSchedule,
)

teacher_with_schedule = Recipe(
    Teacher,
    schedule=foreign_key(schedule),
)
```

Also, it is recommended that you use the updated version of Model Mommy, now known as [Model Bakery](https://github.com/model-bakers/model_bakery).